# Conditional expected value $E[X|X+Y+Z=3]$

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Suppose $X,Y,Z$ are three independent standard normal variables, what are the conditional expected value and variance of $X$, i.e.,
$E[X|X+Y+Z=3]$? $\text{Var}(X|X+Y+Z=3)$?

Comment: Note
$$\mathbb{E}[X \ | \ X+Y+Z = 3] = \mathbb{E}[X \ | \ X = 3-Y-Z] = \mathbb{E}[3-Y-Z \ | \ X  = 3 - Y - Z]$$
To proceed, use the independence of the variables.

Comment: You have to write your own thoughts on the problem. What have you tried?

Comment: Thank you! I was new here and willing to ask a quick question, I will definitely do it next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $~\mathsf E\big(X+Y+Z~\big\vert~ X+Y+Z=3\big)~=~3$

Follow with *Linearity of Expectation* and an argument for symmetry.

Comment: Thanks! The hint is helpful. I did not come up with this trick.